# Using original AsyncTask from Android in libGDX

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, libgdx

I need to use AsyncTask from the `android.os` package. Yes, I know that there is an AsyncTask from the `com.badlogic.utils` package, but I need those one.
So, I imported that:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
```

Used SDK: `Android 20 API Platform.`

And when I try to run, I get errors:

```
Error:(4, 18) error: package android.os does not exist
Error:(146, 38) error: cannot find symbol class AsyncTask
Error:(30, 26) error: cannot find symbol method execute()
Error:(148, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Does this mean that native Android classes are not active in the libGDX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access Android APIs inside `core module`. Core module is generic part for all platforms.

By [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) you can use access platform specific code.